# Using .cfr template create multiple pages pdf with different templates?

Tags: coldfusion, report, reportbuilder

I have gone through the CF Report Builder and built a template and generate a report which is good. I would like to know whether Can we generate a single report using multiple .cfr templates. One template for First page, second template for Second page, so on.. and merge all of them in a PDF. 
Anybody done this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to break the process in 2 steps.

- Step 1 loops through and creates all of the different pages of the report.
- Step 2 merges all of the pages into a single report and removes the single pages.

Comment: <cfquery name="northwindemployees" datasource="test"> 
SELECT
     A, B, C , D FROM
     RST
</cfquery> 
 
<CFREPORT format="RTF" template="NewColdFusionReport.cfr"
query="#northwindemployees#"/> 
 I use the above to generate a word document.  If i want to include multiple pages in a document, does CFREPORT allows to save the pages?